# Reduce startup time when debugging Angular in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I just used the Angular+ASP.NET Core template for a new application, run it in debug mode, stopped it, made no change, re-run it in debug mode and so on.

Startup time is excruciatingly long even with no change whatsoever in between subsequent runs.

I read some time ago that you could keep ng running or something like that to reduce startup time, but I can't find what that is. Is it correct? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes long because each time you run the application, it starts an instance of Angular dev server in the background and rebuilds your client app.

In the `Configure` method of `Startup` class replace

```cs
spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
```

with

```cs
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

This will prevent running the Angular dev server automatically.

Now run the dev server manually with `npm start` and then run your application.

Further detail - [Run "ng serve" independently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-ng-serve-independently)

Comment: but then typescript changes on the UI side arent visible on next studio run..